# equivalent of UserEntityManager of Activiti in Camunda

Tags: user-management, camunda

I'm in the process of moving from Activiti to Camunda.For user management tasks we were using http://javadox.com/org.activiti/activiti-engine/5.16/org/activiti/engine/impl/persistence/entity/UserEntityManager.html#findUserInfoByUserIdAndKey(java.lang.String, java.lang.String).  So while searching I came across DBIdentityServiceProvider class .( http://javadox.com/org.activiti/activiti-engine/5.16/org/activiti/engine/impl/persistence/entity/UserEntityManager.html#findUserInfoByUserIdAndKey(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) Is this the suitable to class ?

Thanks,
masha

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question such that someone who is familiar with Camunda but not with Activiti is able to respond. That means: What kind of feature did you implement using UserEntityManager in Activiti?

Comment: Hi thorben, its an custom identity provider implementation. Also additionally is there any method to retrieve the list of groups for a given user? Was unable to find a method similar . I know you can createMemberships, but is there anyway to retrieve one party (groups/roles) given a user?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `org.camunda.bpm.engine.IdentyService`. This service manages `User`s and `Group`s in Camunda. You find it's JavaDoc here:

https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.4/org/camunda/bpm/engine/IdentityService.html